# Python: why is multiple list comprehensions seemingly faster than a single for loop with if...elif statements?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a bit of code that I am trying to determine if there is a faster way to run it. Essentially, I have a delimited file that I am iterating over to find a set of flags to parse the data. These files can be very long, so I am trying to find a fast method for this.

The two methods I have tried are list comprehension, and a for loop:

Method 1:

```
flag_set_1 = [i for i,row in enumerate(data_file) if row[0] == flag_1]
flag_set_2 = [i for i,row in enumerate(data_file) if row[0] == flag_2]
flag_set_3 = [i for i,row in enumerate(data_file) if row[0] == flag_3]
flag_set_4 = [i for i,row in enumerate(data_file) if row[0] == flag_4]
```

Method 2:

```
for i,row  in enumerate(data_file):
    if row[0] == flag_1:
        flag_set_1.append(i)
    elif row[0] == flag_2:
        flag_set_2.append(i)
    elif row[0] == flag_3:
        flag_set_3.append(i)
    elif row[0] == flag_4:
        flag_set_4.append(i)
```

I was actually expecting the list comprehension to be slower in this case. Thinking that method 1 would have to iterate over data_file 4 times while method 2 would only have to iterate once. I suspect that the use of append() in method 2 is what is slowing it down.

So I ask, is there a quicker way to implement this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621511/do-python-list-comprehensions-append-at-each-iteration

Comment: Basically, list comprehensions are highly optimized.

Comment: Pandas might be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Without any data sample or benchmark, it's hard too reproduce your observation. I tried with:

```
from random import randint
data_file = [[randint(0, 15) for _ in range(20)] for _ in range(100000)]
flag_1 = 1
flag_2 = 2
flag_3 = 3
flag_4 = 4
```

And the regular loop was twice as fast as the four list comprehensions (see benchmark below).

If you want to improve the speed of the process, you have several leads.

## List comprehensions and regular loop

If `flag_n` are strings and you are sure that `row[0]` is one of these for every `row`, then you may check one character instead of the whole string. E.g.:

```
flag_1 = "first flag"
flag_2 = "second flag"
flag_3 = "third flag"
flag_4 = "fourth flag"
```

Look at the second characters: `f<I>rst, S<E>cond, T<H>ird, F<O>urth`. You just have to check if
`row[0][1] == 'i'` (or `'e'` or `'h'` or `'o'`) instead of `row[0] == flag_n`.

## Regular loop

If you want to improve the speed of the regular loop, you have several leads.

### In all cases

You can assign `flag = row[0]` instead of getting `row[0]` the first elements four times. That's basic, but it works.

### If you have information about the data

If the data is sorted by flag, you can obviously build the `flag_n_set` at 
once: find the first the last `flag_n` and write 
`flag_n_set = list(range(first_flag_n_index, last_flag_n_index+1))`.

If you know the frequency of the flags, you can order the `if ... elif ... 
elif ... elif ... else` to first check the more frequent 
flag, then the second most frequent flag, etc.

You can also use a dict to avoid the `if ... elif ...` sequence. If you don't 
have too many rows that don't match any flag, you can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def test_append_default_dict():
    flag_set = defaultdict(list)

    for i, row  in enumerate(data_file):
        flag_set[row[0]].append(i)

    return tuple(flag_set[f] for f in (flag_1, flag_2, flag_3, flag_4))
```

---

Benchmarks with the data above:

```
test_list_comprehensions    3.8617278739984613
test_append                 1.9978336450003553
test_append_default_dict    1.4595633919998363
```